# Windows event, when wifi connection attempt is made

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wifi

I want to create an application(in c++), which tells me about access point authentication algorithm. And also warns me, if I tries to connect to wifi, which doesn't use WPA2 AES encryption algo.

If I get widows event information, while connection attempt is made, probably I can write a hook to check the encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WlanRegisterNotification()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706771.aspx) to listen for WiFi events.

You can use [`WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749.aspx) to get a list of available WiFi networks and their details, including authorization algorithm+cipher and current connection state.